# Get coordinates of one mouse click

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am using [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java.html) class from Sedgewick and Wayne and I need to get the coordinates from a mouse click when it is pressed at the standard draw window. This class have a method boolean mousePressed that identifies when mouse is pressed and we can get the coordinates from a point when the mouse is pressed at that point. I've tried to modify the java code to do something similar for a mouse click:

```
public static boolean mouseClicked() {
    synchronized (mouseLock) {
        return mouseClicked;
    }
}
```

.
.
.

```
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     synchronized (mouseLock) {
         mouseX = StdDraw.userX(e.getX());
         mouseY = StdDraw.userY(e.getY());
         mouseClicked = true;
     }
}
```

...

```
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    synchronized (mouseLock) {
        mousePressed = false;
        mouseClicked = false;
    }
}
```

If I run the following program

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
        if (StdDraw.mouseClicked()) {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

}

It keeps printing hello (so it means that mouseClicked is returning true. How can I make it stop? I've tried to set mouseClicked=false on released event, but didnt work. What am I doing wrong? First, I've tried to use mousePressed to get the point, but I couldn't use it to get two points.

Thanks!

Comment: Make MouseClicked volatile

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't understand how this can help.

Comment: You have a potential thread race condition, where one thread isn't reading the actual value which the other is changing.  See [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) for some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `mouseClicked` flag false after printing the value

```
while (true) {
        if (StdDraw.mouseClicked()) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            StdDraw.mouseClicked=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how can I write a code to get the first point, then the second one? I've tried while (StdDraw.mousePressed()){ // get the coordinates } and then added another loop to get the second one, but it always catch the same point twice!

Comment: If you could add an example that you can get two different points, I would be glad. By the way, I don't want to draw the point, I need its coordinate in my main program (that is coded in another class)

Comment: I have updated the code with an example.I guess that would suffice your query

Comment: I am using StdDraw as an auxiliar class. I need the points on my main class, not the program to print it or something.  Thats why I want to identificate a click: to get the first point on the first click, the second one from the second click and so on.

Comment: Hey Now I got your question correctly. I've edited the code check

Comment: I will test it when I gent back on my computer, but it looks good! Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to add Thread.sleep(100) before repeting the loop to catch the other point.